# after dismiss a view, toolbar button item on parent view's toolbar disappear

Tags: ios, ios6

On ios6, after executing `[parentView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];` the toolbar button item on parent view's toolbar disappear.
Those toolbar button items are created in storyboard.

It works well on ios5 though ...

What happen here?

Comment: Are they shown without title?